# Qt QGraphicsItem move animation

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I'd like to now how should I code "move animation" on QGraphicsItem. Something similar to moveBy(qreal, qreal) but not instant. Should I look for it in QtAnimation Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [QPropertyAnimation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html). For some example code, see [Animating graphics item position](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Archived:Animating_graphics_item_position_in_Qt)